# text in right column is going below image in left column

Tags: css, image

EDIT: I was able to fix this problem by switching to a float based layout. Not sure if there is a solution to the problem using an inline-block based grid. (I suppose I could use the position:relative or absolute, but that seems to be a bad idea.) Here's my Codepen: https://codepen.io/mattgwater/pen/yXBqoe (It works if full-screen) Ehsan's answer demonstrates how to basically do this layout too and probably is a better example of good code.

I am trying to build a website based on the template in the picture here. https://assets.themuse.com/uploaded/attachments/14846.png?v=None

However, if I have an image in the left column it causes all the text in the right column to go below the image. How can I fix this problem?

Here is my Codepen: https://codepen.io/mattgwater/pen/yXBqoe?editors=1100#0

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Fonts/myFontsWebfontsKit/MyFontsWebfontsKit.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="col left">
      <div>
        <h1 class="title">MATT GOLDWATER</h1>
      </div>
    </div><!--
    --><div class="col right">
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="nav-content-separator"></div>
  <section>
    <div class="col left">
      <img class="profilepic" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dyr8j9g6m/image/upload/v1496375439/my-headshot_bxpjqk.png" alt="Matt Goldwater">
        <!--<p>yo</p>-->
    </div><!--
    --><div class="col right">
      <p class="about">I want this sentence to be aligned with the top of the image.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS (I also have normalize CSS)

```
    html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.title {
  color: #6fc3c3;
  /*font-family: FuturaDCD-Lig;*/
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 32px; 
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: .05em;
}

.col {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  /*white-space: nowrap;*/
}

.left {
  padding-left: 10%;
}

.profilepic {
  padding-top: 7%;
  height: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

.nav-content-separator {
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}

.about {
  font-family: Avenir;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your CSS please?

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy Whoops! Just did.

Comment: What if you try adding `float: right;` to `.col.right`?

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy That gets my text to the very top of the column, but when I add 7% padding in an effort to get the text at the same point as the top of the circle it moves below the image again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I changed your code,use wrapper and float and other Properties.

```css
#wrapper {
 max-width: 1200px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}  
.title {
 color: #6fc3c3;
 float: left;
}

.right {
 float: right;
}

.left {
 float: left;
}

ul {
 list-style-type: none;

}

li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 1%;
}
li a {
 color: #ccc;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.col {
 width: 50%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
 border-bottom: #ccc solid 1px;
 overflow: auto;
}

.profilepic {
max-width: 410px;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
   <nav>
     <div class="col title"><h2>KRISTA GRAY</h2></div>
     <div class="col right">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Journal</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
   </nav>

   <div class="container">
    <div class="col left">
     <img class="profilepic" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1424/5850/products/Circular_Stickers_CG_1024x1024.jpg?v=1486690726" alt="Me">
    </div>
    <div class="right col">
     <h4>Lorem Ipsum: common examples</h4>
     <p>Lorem ipsum is a pseudo-Latin text used in web design, typography, layout, and printing in place of English to emphasise design elements over content. It's also called placeholder (or filler) text. It's a convenient tool for mock-ups. It helps to outline the visual elements of a document or presentation, eg typography, font, or layout. Lorem ipsum is mostly a part of a Latin text by the classical author and philosopher Cicero. Its words and letters have been changed by addition or removal, so to deliberately render its content nonsensical; it's not genuine, correct, or comprehensible Latin anymore. While lorem ipsum's still resembles classical Latin, it actually has no meaning whatsoever. As Cicero's text doesn't contain the letters K, W, or Z, alien to latin, these, and others are often inserted randomly to mimic the typographic appearence of European languages, as are digraphs not to be found in the original.
     </p>
    </div>

   </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Few modifications in your code:

- Give image `max-width:100%` so that image stay within the parent. Remove `display:block` from image style.
- Add `white-space:nowrap` in the `section` style so that the whitespace is ignored. We need to ignore whitespace because `.left` and `.right` are set to `width:50%` and hence even a pixel of whitespace will break the layout.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/1952/

```
.profilepic {
  padding-top: 7%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline;
}

section {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: This didn't change anything for me.  The image isn't at 100% width and I have comments in the HTML to make the column layout work. To be clear the text is on the right side as its supposed to be. The problem is that its below the content on the left when there is an image.

Comment: @MJGwater Did you checked the demo?

Comment: Yeah. But when I copy and paste the stuff from your demo its not changing anything on my computer. I've tried multiple times. (Maybe there's an issue with normalize.css)

Comment: Also. I want my text on the right column to start at the point of the top of the image in the left column. (i.e the top of the circle) (Sorry if that wasn't clear)

Answer (score 0):

See your col class have width of 50% and then you are also adding padding-left of 10%. So it is going more than 100%. Play with the col width, make it 40% and it should work.

Comment: I set box-sizing to border-box in my CSS so that doesn't fix the problem. To be clear my text is in the right hand column. It's just below the content on the left whenever the content on the left has an image.